# WCF way to communicate client with multiple server

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I need to create .NET desktop app that will be sending request to windows services on many machines and as callback recieve list of values. I need to know if there is a way to client app to reconnect between two or more servers.

**Example**: I run client app, receive my list then pass IP of other server and receive list from second machine etc.. I thought I could change endpoint address in app.config and reconnect WCF service, but I don't know if it will work, and if it is proper way to do something like this.

**My question is**: I even possible reconnecting client app to other instance of the service and if is then which binding should I use to do this? I thought about `nettcpbinding` but this is my very first task in WCF and I feel like walking in the mist, so I would appreciate if someone could help me find the right way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure your WCF client to specify the IP address:

```
var client = new MyService.MyClient();
client.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("192.168.0.1"));
client.Open();
```

Comment: I understand that 192.168.0.1 is ip of server. What should I set then in server endpoint? And do you think netTcpBinding is best way to achieve my goals?

Comment: You don't need to change anything on the server. It accepts connections from any clients. Also, you don't need to modify your app.config (or web.config) on the client, either.